# "NOT IN" not working as expected

Tags: sql, oracle

I was writing a query to find the node type from the table BST ordered by the value of the node.
table, BST, had two columns N and P, where N represents the value of a node in BST, and P is the parent of N.
say, BST has following records:
  [BST Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ufmex.png)

I successfully executed the query as follows:

```
SELECT n,CASE
                WHEN p IS NULL THEN 'Root'
                WHEN n IN (SELECT DISTINCT p FROM BST) THEN 'Inner'
                ELSE 'Leaf'
             END
FROM BST
ORDER BY n;
```

Result: [Result as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEIyw.jpg)

But instead of using "IN", when I tried the same query using "NOT IN" as given below:

```
SELECT n,CASE
            WHEN p IS NULL THEN 'Root'
            WHEN n NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT p FROM BST) THEN 'Leaf'
            ELSE 'Inner'
         END
FROM BST
ORDER BY n;
```

it didn't work as expected. Why so?

Comment: NOT IN and NULL's may surprise you! (That's why I recommend `NOT EXISTS` instead.)

Comment: "*it didn't work as expected.*" - so what did you expect?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I expected it to give the same output as using with "IN"

Comment: Side note: Smart optimizers don't need your assistance - `DISTINCT` is irrelevant when you're performing a set-based operation such as `IN`. Dumb optimizers won't realize they don't need your help and will actually perform the `DISTINCT` operation. Since neither smart nor dumb optimizers benefit from the `DISTINCT` being in there, what product are you working with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jarlh suggested, use NOT EXISTS, or when using NOT IN, be sure to exclude NULLs from your subquery like:

```
SELECT n,CASE
            WHEN p IS NULL THEN 'Root'
            WHEN n NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT p FROM BST WHERE p IS NOT NULL) THEN 'Leaf'
            ELSE 'Inner'
         END
FROM BST
ORDER BY n;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd just a NOT EXISTS. I used to always use NOT IN as a beginner. Later on I realized that you need to consider quite a bit of different factors that you never thought of at first. Use WHERE NOT EXISTS and you'll be happy fellow.

Cheers!

Comment: Can you show how can i use NOT EXISTS here in place of NOT IN